# Efficient way of indexing a specific number from a text file

Tags: bash, indexing

I have a text file containing a line of various numbers (i.e. 2 4 1 7 12 1 4 4 3 1 1 2)

I'm trying to get the index for each occurrence of 1. This is my code for what I'm currently doing (subtracting each index value by 1 since my indexing starts at 0).

```
eq='0'
gradvec=()
count=0
length=0
for item in `cat file`
do
    ((count++))
    if (("$item"=="$eq"))
    then
            ((length++))
            if (("$length"=='1'))
            then
                    gradvec=$((count -1))
            else
                    gradvec=$gradvec' '$((count - 1))
            fi
    fi
done
```

Although the code works, I was wondering if there was a shorter way of doing this? The result is the gradvec variable being

```
2 5 9 10
```

Comment: You are trying to use BASH as a general purpose programming language. It is often frowned upon, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/17649. You could get the problem solved using e.g. grep in one line.

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Put `((count++))` at the end of the loop so you don't have to subtract 1.

Comment: Use an array instead of a string, then you don't need `if (($length == 1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this as the input file:

```
$ cat file
2 4 1 7 12 1
 4 4 3 1 1 2
```

To get the indices of every occurrence of `1` in the input file:

```
$ awk '$1==1 {print NR-1}' RS='[[:space:]]+' file                                 
2                                                                                         
5                                                                                         
9                                                                                         
10
```

How it works:

- `$1==1 {print NR-1}`

  If the value in any record is `1`, print the record number minus 1.
- `RS='[[:space:]]+'`

  Define the record separator as one or more of any kind of space.